# PHP: Searching for an exact string pattern in array elements

Tags: php, regex, foreach

I want to validate all the files that are being uploaded on my site through PHP. I am using regular expressions to compare the file contents but it doesn't seem to be working as I expect it to work. I want to accept files with 1 term per line only.

```
EXPECTED INPUT:
HP34930
HP09099
HP98899

UNACCEPTABLE INPUT:
HP89980 HP98798 HP09232
some other text
HP58089
```

Here is my code:

```
$texthandle = file($_FILES["textfile"]["tmp_name"]);
foreach ($texthandle as $textline)
{
    if (!preg_match("/(HP\d+){1}/", $textline))
    {
    echo "Incorrect file format. Please provide a text file with 1 term per line.";
            exit(0);
    }       
}
```

Could someone suggest why this isn't detecting the way I want it to?

I have also tried

```
if (!preg_match("/^(HP\d+){1}$/", $textline))
```

but it isn't working as I expect it to work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a proper issue explanation. As well as "isn't working correctly". Only you know what "correctly" means.

Comment: I have made some edits to be less ambiguous. I hope that helps.

Comment: I took your code and it **does work** http://ideone.com/I1sRLt

Comment: @Mike W: the whole file is not. OP checks line by line and the result if the whole file is good or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what not working is, but try:

```
$texthandle = file($_FILES["textfile"]["tmp_name"], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

and then:

```
if (!preg_match("/^HP\d+$/", $textline))
```

or if there are only 5 digits allowed:

```
if (!preg_match("/^HP[\d]{5}$/", $textline))
```

If there is any whitespace at the end like spaces, tabs, etc. it will fail, so you can try trim() on $textline.

Comment: Your regex is identical (by behaviour) to the OP's one

Comment: The difference is the `^` and `$` characters; these check for the start and end of the line, respectively.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell: there are anchors in the second OP's attempt

Comment: @zerkms: Could work sort of the same, or not, but definitely not identical :)  And, maybe it's not the regex?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: it's identical to `/^(HP\d+){1}$/` from the question. If you see the differences between your and this one - please share.

Comment: "And, maybe it's not the regex?" --- it's definitely something else. That's why instead of blindly trying to guess, I'm asking OP about the details.

Comment: @zerkms: I only looked at the first one and wasn't attempting to fix the regex, just used what I would use.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I don't see the main point of this answer then :-) PS: `[\d]` is weird

Comment: Sorry, @zerkms, I think I missed an edit to the OP or something.